# How to scroll an active accordion to the the top before expanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I have created an accordion using html , css and jquery

Whenever a accordion is expanded , i would like the accordion title to scroll and sit at the very top of the page before expanding ( excluding a little space so that it doesn't cover my fixed navbar )

I would like to this to be applicable on every accordion irrespective of its default position 
( Eg. a accordion at the lower bottom of page should first scroll to the top before expanding itself )

I tried using scrollTop(0) for the relevant css class but it doesn't seem to work

It just needs some changes in Jquery code

Hope someone would be able to help

Attaching all codes in snippets
( For this particular example , i have placed one accordion at the very top of the page and one at the lower bottom , so that its easy to check if someone's query fixed code is working as intended )

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  function close_accordion_section() {
    $('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
    $('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
  }

  $('.accordion-section-title').click(function (e) {
    // Grab current anchor value
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

    if ($(e.target).is('.active')) {
      close_accordion_section();
    } else {
      close_accordion_section();

      // Add active class to section title
      $(this).addClass('active');
      // Open up the hidden content panel
      $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open')
    }

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
/*----- Accordion -----*/

.accordion,
.accordion * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion {
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

/*----- Section Titles -----*/

.accordion-section-title {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  background: #333;
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  /* Type */
  font-size: 1.200em;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #1a1a1a;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (hover: hover) {
  .accordion-section-title:hover {
   background: #4c4c4c;
   text-decoration: none;
   opacity: 0.5;
  }
}

.accordion-section-title.active{
  background: #4c4c4c;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.accordion-section:last-child .accordion-section-title {
  border-bottom: none;
}

/*----- Section Content -----*/

.accordion-section-content {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-section">
    <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">Accordion Section #1</a>
    <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
      <p>Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Duis congue ullamcorper vehicula. Proin nunc lacus, semper sit amet elit sit amet, aliquet pulvinar erat. Nunc pretium quis sapien eu rhoncus. Suspendisse ornare gravida mi, et placerat tellus tempor vitae.
What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
    </div>
    <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
  </div>
  <!--end .accordion-section-->
</div>
<!--end .accordion-->



Body Text Starts here<br><br>
What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-section">
    <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-2">Accordion Section #2</a>
    <div id="accordion-2" class="accordion-section-content">
      <p>Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Duis congue ullamcorper vehicula. Proin nunc lacus, semper sit amet elit sit amet, aliquet pulvinar erat. Nunc pretium quis sapien eu rhoncus. Suspendisse ornare gravida mi, et placerat tellus tempor vitae.
What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
    </div>
    <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
  </div>
  <!--end .accordion-section-->
</div>
<!--end .accordion-->
```

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll

Replace the code

```
$('.accordion-section-content').scrollTop(0);
```

for

```
$(".accordion-section a").on('click', function (event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
        // Prevent default anchor click behavior
        event.preventDefault();

        // Store hash
        var hash = this.hash;

        // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 800, function () {

            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
            window.location.hash = hash;
        });
    } // End if
});
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/gemaworofo/edit?output. Your code. Isn't working well.  1) Causing a lot of lags 2) Tapping on accordion at bottom isn't Scrolling it to top of page     I think you should rather look to replace slideup300 intial codes.  Because that be conflicting with ur jquery

Comment: The 1 line code that you have instructed to replace doesn't even deal with scrolling of accordion. That is just for keeping the content of a accordion to top if its closed and reopened , after someone scrolls till a particular point ..That line is for this purpose

Comment: I have removed that line from question so people don't get confused

Comment: @BadalSingh Interesting, because in my fiddle it worked: https://jsfiddle.net/dkorber/2740gj1x/6/

But yes, the slideUp part needs to be commented.

Comment: i checked it. Sorry maybe i made my mistake in my js bin. Ignore that for now. Talking of your jsfiddle.1) If i tap on the accordion at bottom , few lines from the body are visible at top. Can you adjust it to occupy the space little above. 2) Tapping on first accordion at top moves the accordion title up ..since its already up , shouldn't it just stay there on its place and expand .

Comment: What you are asking for depends on a lot of factors like screen size and css setup for instance. This has to be fixed in your code by yourself. The question was about scrolling to the top and the suggested code does this.